# Changing row selection of e = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Tags: vba, excel

I  have this piece of excel vba code that helps to display combobox from Column C16 till the last row of excel. However, I would like it only display from row C16 - C20 and C25 - last row. How can I achieve this with my existing code? I think the code line I'm pointing at could be altered but I don't know how to work with it.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Count = 1 And Target.Row > 15 And Target.Column = 3 Then
    Dim e As Long
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Setting")
    If Not IsArray(priArray) Then


        e = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '<<<<<<<<

        priArray = sh.Range("C5:C" & e).Value2
    End If
    Call ShowComboBox
Else
    Call HideComboBox
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set an array's elements (aka *values*) from a discontiguous range, even if that range has been unioned. You will have to construct it brick-by-brick.

```
Dim priArray As Variant
Dim c As Long, e As Long

With Worksheets("Setting")
    ReDim priArray(0)
    For e = 16 To .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Select Case e
            Case 16 To 20, Is >= 25
                priArray(UBound(priArray)) = .Range("C" & e).Value2
                ReDim Preserve priArray(UBound(priArray) + 1)
            Case Else
                'do nothing
        End Select
    Next e
    ReDim Preserve priArray(UBound(priArray) - 1)
End With

'do something with the loaded priArray here
```

Comment: shouldn't be simpler (and faster)  to `ReDim priArray(1000)` (something huge just for init.), and then at the end to `ReDim Preserve priArray` only once ?

Comment: If I went back to the OP's method of setting `e = sh.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row` then `Redim priArray(e)` could be used without worrying that you had enough room but you would also have to increment a counter var every time you used one of the preset elements in order to know the correct size to `ReDim Preserve priArray(e - 1)`. While multiple `ReDim Preserve ...` commands (looped) are somewhat slower, in my experience you have to perform it about 100K times before a human would notice the difference.